# In a hierarchy, how son constructor can set members of grandfather constructor in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

In a hierarchy, how son constructor can set members of grandfather constructor in c++.

grandfather>father>son

Comment: The C++ terminology is based class (father) and derived class (son). Smalltalk terminlogy is superclass (father) and subclass (son).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Person{
 int age;
 protected :
  string name;
  public:
   Person(int a,string s)
   {
    age=a;
    name=s;
   }
   Display_0()
   {
    cout<<"\nName          : "<<name;
    cout<<"\nAge           : "<<age;
   }

};

class Employe {
 int employeid;
 protected :
  double salary;
  public:
   Employe(int id,double sal)  
   {
    employeid=id;
    salary=sal;

   }

   Display_1()
  {


   cout<<"Id is         : "<<employeid;
   cout<<"\nSalary is     : "<<salary;
  }
};

 class Manager : public Person, public Employe
{
 string type;

 public:
  Manager(string t,int id,double sal,int age,string name)   : Employe( id, sal) , Person( age, name)
  {
   type=t;
  }
 string get_type()
  {
   return type;
  }

  Display_2()
  {
  Display_0();
  cout << "\n";
   Display_1();
   cout<<"\nType is       : "<<type;
  }
};

class It_Manager : public  Manager{
 private :
  int noOfPersons;
  public:
   It_Manager(int n,string na,int id,double sal,int age,string name) : Manager( na, id, sal, age, name)
   {
    noOfPersons=n;
   }

   Display_last()
   {
    Display_2();
    cout<<"\nNo of Persons : "<<noOfPersons;
   }

};
main()
{
   It_Manager b(1,"Computer Scientist",152118,150000,100,"Muhammad Owais") ;
   b.Display_last() ;

}
```

here 
It_Manager is son
Manager is father
and Person and Employe are grandfather

with the help of this you can have basic concept and about printing data that depend on you how you do than. one can use member function to print it.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It can not, at least not with the initialiser syntax. Given classes like these

```
class grandfather {
  int x;
};
class father : public grandfather {
  int y;
};
class son : public father {
  int z;

  son();
};
```

writing

```
son::son() : x(0), y(1), z(2) { }
```

is not valid. Only the direct base class constructor is available, base members are not. This is possible:

```
son::son() : father(), z(2) {
  x = 0;
  y = 1;
}
```

But it would be better to add constructors to `father` and `grandfather` like this

```
grandfather::grandfather(int xx) :
  x(xx) { }
father::father(int xx, int yy) :
  grandfather(xx), y(yy) { }
```

and then `son` like this

```
son::son() : father(0, 1), z(2) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't. That is not its job. Each "level" may initialise only the "level" above it. That's as it should be.

However, this rule goes away when you use virtual inheritance, and each "level" becomes directly responsible for providing constructor arguments for every other "level".

Comment: Re «Each "level" may initialise only the "level" above it.», that's doesn't hold for virtual inheritance. I.e. it's incorrect as a general statement.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Um, read the second paragraph? I literally said all that.

Comment: @mytime: No, it is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No sorry I didn't read that far. I think I would have noted it if you noted the exception first, or directly in connection with the statement. E.g. as a footnote on a weasel word (which would be my preference in this case). ;-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how you can say it is not correct. It is working perfectly

Comment: @mytime: It is _impossible_ to initialise a non-direct base unless you're using virtual inheritance. It's as simple as that. Either you are misinterpreting your results, or you are describing them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You use member initializer lists to pass arguments to a direct base class constructor.

Like

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
        : Base( "joo hoo" )         // ← A member initializer list
    {}
};
```

The base class constructor will in turn pass arguments to *its* base class' constructor, and so on.

It's only in the case of *virtual inheritance* that a derived-of derived-of derived-… class can directly initialize a "grandfather" class. And that's an advanced topic, unlikely to be what you're asking about now. I suggest you ask a new question about it if you encounter that issue.

---

Regarding terminology:

- The C++ terminology is **base class** (father) and **derived class** (son).
- The Smalltalk terminology is **superclass** (father) and **subclass** (son).

The terms *father* and *son* are generally not used (it's the first time I see them!), but sometimes one uses **parent** and **child** to denote placements in a hierarchy  –  of nodes, classes, whatever.

Related, although not used in this question, a *pure virtual* function in C++ corresponds to a method that's *subclass responsibility* in Smalltalk.